# Retrieve Landing Page Pageviews from Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to extract pageviews for landing page, 
The pageviews shown in google anlytic Report page is shown in below image

[image]

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Nice! Sonal, you should put your answer in as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the [landingpagepath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_landingpagepath) dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Landing Page is the first page load in any website, its called landing page in google analytic. If you want to get landing page view you can use below code

```
$landingPages = $ga->getReport(
        array('dimensions'=>urlencode('ga:pagePath'),
            'metrics'=>urlencode('ga:pageviews'),
            'max-results' => $limit,
            'filters' => urlencode('ga:pagePath==/')
        )
    )
```

Important part is :  `'filters' => urlencode('ga:pagePath==/')`

Comment: I already get landing page data successfully, i want city name with according visits